# Querying data on json saved using ReJSON

Tags: redis, redisjson

i have saved one json using Rejson against a key,now i would like to filter/query out data using ReJson.

Please let me know how can i do it ...python prefered .

```
print("Abount to execute coomnad")
    response=redisClient.execute_command('JSON.SET', 'object', '.', json.dumps(data))
    print(response)
    reply = json.loads(redisClient.execute_command('JSON.GET', 'object'))
    print(reply)
```

using  the above code i was able to set data using ReJson .now lets suppose i want to filer data .

my test json is  :

```
data = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'ans': 42
}
```

How can you filter say json in which foo has value as bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis in general, and ReJSON specifically, do not provide search-by-value functionality. For that, you'll have to either index the values yourself (see https://redis.io/topics/indexes) or use [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/).

Comment: I am trying to do a similar process, were you able to find a way?

Comment: It just so happens that the other day we've launched its preview: https://redis.com/blog/redisjson-public-preview-performance-benchmarking/